# How do I dynamically color stars in a star rating?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, rating

I have a form where users can rate a product, where I need to visually show a star rating. I need to colour the stars according to the rating value I'm retrieving from the database, for each user as well as an overall average.

For example, user A has given a 5 star rating, and user B has given 3 stars only.  When I display the rating of user A, I have to colour all 5 stars, but when I display the rating of user B, I have to colour only 3 stars.  That means I have to dynamically colour the stars.

I have also seen on most sites when displaying average ratings, they have coloured half of the star where the average rating ends in half a star.  I would like to do that too.

My display does not need to contain a hover feature.

My question is about how to colour the stars according to the calculated average or the rating pulled from the database.

I'm using codeigniter in my project.

Thank you for any help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Have one `<span>` element nested inside another.
The outer `<span>` has a background image of empty stars.
The inner `<span>` has a background image of a colored-in star, and a `width:` element that is programmatically set when you layout the page.  For example, `width:60.0%` could be used for a 3/5 star rating.

For a small optimization, you may even use start with an image that is only one star and use repeat-x to get all 5 stars.  You could also have an image that includes both colored and filled-in stars vertically, and crop at display time to determine which version of the star you are referencing.

### Example 1:

For example, consider the following CSS:

```
span.rating-frame, span.rating-fill {
    background: url(../star.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
    display: block;
    width: 80px; /* this is 5 times the width of the star, for 5 stars total */
    height: 16px;
}
span.rating-fill {
    background-position: 0 0; /* use the (filled-in) version from the top of the image */
}
```

and the following HTML:

```
Average Rating: 4/5
<span class="rating-frame">
      <span style="width:80.0%;" class="rating-fill"> </span>
</span>

User A:  5/5
<span class="rating-frame">
      <span style="width:100.0%;" class="rating-fill"> </span>
</span>

User B: 3/5
<span class="rating-frame">
      <span style="width:60.0%;" class="rating-fill"> </span>
</span>
```

This assumes that star.png is a 16x32 image with the filled-in star on top.
The value for the width attribute is set by `userRating/maxPossibleRating` rounded to an appropriate precision.  Of course, where you show the overall average rating, it's set by `averageUserRating/maxPossibleRating`.

---

### Example 2:

OP reports using `<span>☆</span>` instead.  The following pseudocode might be helpful in page generation there.

```
for (i = 1 to rating inclusive) {
    print "<span>★</span>"
}
//if including a half-star, replace this comment with the code to do so.
for (i = rating+1 to maxRating inclusive) {
    print "<span>☆</span>"
}
```

but unless you have a half-filled star character, you won't be able to use that in your output. You might try using the ½ character instead.

---

### Example 3:

The eBay example OP links to uses source like this:

```
   <span class="display-text-rating">3.7 stars</span>
   <div class="star-rating-section" title="3.7 out of 5 stars">
     <span class="star-rating" role="img" aria-label="3.7 stars">
         <i class="fullStar"></i>
         <i class="fullStar"></i>
         <i class="fullStar"></i>
         <i class="midStar"></i>
         <i class="emptyStar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
```

The first line is the printed text showing the rating in text form.
The div title shows that information on mouse hover.
The elements w/class attributes inside the span could easily be programmatically generated as in example 2.  The CSS could be set to use different images for fullStar, midStar, and emptyStar.  This generation process could be repeated for each user in the section where the users' individual ratings go.

**Example 3 has the disadvantage of visually rounding to the nearest half-star (and example 2, to the full star), while example 1 permits more fine-grained distinction of fractional stars without requiring extra programming or image creation.**  Deciding on the appropriate level of rounding is a question for [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) (and if anyone does care enough to ask it, please edit in a link here).

Comment: I'm using <span>☆</span> in my code , i'm not using images, but for that even is it still the same way i need to follow.

Comment: @mad_ss You're using the star character instead of images, and expect to get a half a colored star? Do you have a half-colored character to put in? Is there a particular reason you don't want to use images?  With the characters, just write a loop in whatever you're using to generate the page, to print the proper number of filled-in and empty star characters, based on the user rating.

Comment: yeah why is it cannot be done, because different ads in my site has different ratings, so if one ad has average rating of 4.7 i need to colour it according to that value, if another ad has 3.2 average rating it should be coloured into according to that value(means 3.2), and also think for a particular ad one user has given 3 star rating , other one has given only one star so i need to show these each and every users individual ratings also in my site.when i display them i need to colour the stars according to that users given rating value.

Comment: i need to do somewhat like this http://www.ebay.com/urw/product-reviews/1154802091?_itm=311530352979

Comment: there you can see 4.7 is the average rating it has displayed onthe top. and each and every users individual reviews also has posted below. infront of the reviews they have coloured and displayed the no of stars that each user has given

Comment: @mad_ss eBay uses images. Do the new examples help?

Comment: if i use 3rd  example , i need to use first get images,  fully coloured image,half coloured image and empty image am i right?and also here you have used classes like class="fullStar",class="star-rating-section",class="star-rating", class="display-text-rating"why did you use those things can you explain little bit

Comment: can you please kindly consider and explain little bit about third example. am i need to use images for that