# Looking for a cleaner way to echo a Font Awesome icon with operators

Tags: php, operators

The variable `$fields['score']` returns a value between 1 to 5. Depending on the score it either returns `<i class="fas fa-star"></i>` or `<i class="far fa-star"></i>`. I currently have the code here below, which works perfectly. But I am looking for a less repetitive way to achieve this. Any suggestions?

```
<?php if ( $fields['score'] >= 1 ) {
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
} else {
   echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
}
    
if ( $fields['score'] >= 2 ) {
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
} else {
   echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
}
    
if ( $fields['score'] >= 3 ) {
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
} else {
   echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
}
    
if ( $fields['score'] >= 4 ) {
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
} else {
   echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
}
    
if ( $fields['score'] >= 5 ) {
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
} else {
   echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
} ?>
```

Comment: Something based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250825/converting-numbers-to-visual-rating-stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        $value = $fields['score'];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            if ($value >= $i) {
                echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>' . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>' . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
```